# Excel: How to have an IF function return the value of the cell from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2013

This is sort of a carry on from my previous question. I have a sheet named `Car Search` which returns the details of a car from the `Raw Data` sheet when the Car ID is entered (see image 1).

I would like the `Notes` column to return what is in the `Raw Data` sheet in that specific cell. This is dynamic; so if the cell was F561, then I would like it to return that exact cell.

So for example, when I enter the Car ID '2613' into the `Car Search` sheet, I would like column ***E5*** to return the value of the specific cell in the `Raw Data` tab. (Currently, that cell is F5 which is 'here2').

Is there a formula that can do this? Or am I missing something in the current formula?

My current formula is this: `=IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!E:F,MATCH($B$3,'Raw Data'!A:A,0),MATCH(E2,'Raw Data'!1:1,0))="","")`

[image: Car Search sheet]
[image: Raw data sheet]

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: I notice you have `'Raw Data'!E:F` for your Index array. Are you pulling the location for B5 as well? Maybe you need the values to be static instead ($E:$F)?

Comment: Yep, all cells except for B14, C14 and D14 in that column are being pulled from the `Raw Data` sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **untested** formula:

```
=""&INDEX('Raw Data'!$F:$F,MATCH($B$3,'Raw Data'!$A:$A,0))
```

Comment: It returns as #REF!

Comment: That formula works, however, it still returns '0' if the actual cell is blank. The other formula you provided worked fine: `=IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$A:$F,MATCH($B$3,'Raw Data'!$A:$A,0),6)<>"",INDEX('Raw Data'!$A:$F,MATCH($B$3,'Raw Data'!$A:$A,0),6),"")`

Is there a shorter version of this?

Comment: @howzat You would just need to wrap it in an `IF()` formula, which is not much shorter. I'll change it. If it answers your question would you mark as correct? :-)

Comment: Or you can try @UlliSchmid idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your Index() formula is searching within E:F, but the column index you supply is actually identical with the column id. So change this to A:Z.

Also, I'd suggest some "$" since it looks like you wish to drag this formula:

```
=""&INDEX('Raw Data'!$A:$Z,MATCH($B$3,'Raw Data'!$A:$A,0),MATCH(E$2,'Raw Data'!$1:$1,0))
```

Wrapping it with `IF(Result="","",Result)` is kind of redundant - it serves no function.

Comment: Nice trick there with `=""&`! I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: yes, it works here because it changes *blank* to *""*, but won't affect string outputs.